# Working with multiple monitors

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have two monitors on my desk, they are both the same resolution and screen size, but they are from different manufacturers - one is LG, the other is Dell. Using their default settings, the two render things quite differently, i.e. the same content looks much different when moved from one monitor to the other. Is there a quick way to get the two to render things somewhat closely. I understand that you cannot make two different monitors look like each other, but I expect that you can get close, at least the same amount of brightness, contrast, hues, etc. Is painfull trial and error tweaking the brightness, contrast settings on both my only option?

Is there perhaps a utility that knows the display characteristics of various monitors, and can suggest me display settings based on that knowledge?

Comment: You don't tell us how they look different.  Have you tried just adjusting the settings on each monitor to see if that helps?

Comment: @Ramhound That is my question - must I tweak the settings in a trial and error fashion (which is painful), or is there perhaps a utility that knows the display characteristics of various monitors, and can suggest me display settings based on that knowledge

Comment: @Ramhound Brightness and color look different

Comment: One normally adjusts the color and brightness of a monitor themselfs.